# UITableView not displaying data after altering frame and transform properties

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

I have created a tableView and changed it transform and frame properties mostly because i want it work much like a scrollView(with lazy loading).

```
        UITableView *tempTableView = [[UITableView alloc] init];

        //Rotating it 90`
        tempTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1.5707);
        tempTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, 768, 79);
```

A little later in the application i need to change the size of the tableView 
this seems to fail(the tableViews contents are no more visible although the table view itself is) wether i try to edit the tables 'frame' or 'bounds' properties

Answer (score 0):

Use addSubview method in your code.

```
tempTableView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-1.5707);
tempTableView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 30, 768, 79);
 //tempTableView.frame =  CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);
[self.view addSubview:tempTableView];
```